# Typescript only raises error only if file is imported

Tags: typescript

So this is my JSON file:

```
 [
   {
      "kids":{
         "has_relatives":{
            "records":[
               {
                  "kids":{

                  }
               },
               {
                  "kids":{
                     "has_phone":{
                        "records":[

                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
 ]
```

And this is my code:

```
import data from './data.json'
interface Node {
  kids: NodeKids
}

interface NodeAttributes {
  [key: string]: string;
}

interface NodeKids {
  [key: string]: RecordedNode;
}

interface RecordedNode {
  records: Node[]
}

let dataTyped: Node[] = data
```

This returns a somewhat nonsensical error message:

```
Type '{ kids: { has_relatives: { records: ({ kids: { has_phone?: undefined; }; } | { kids: { has_phone: { records: never[]; }; }; })[]; }; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Node[]'.
  Type '{ kids: { has_relatives: { records: ({ kids: { has_phone?: undefined; }; } | { kids: { has_phone: { records: never[]; }; }; })[]; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
    Types of property 'kids' are incompatible.
      Type '{ has_relatives: { records: ({ kids: { has_phone?: undefined; }; } | { kids: { has_phone: { records: never[]; }; }; })[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'NodeKids'.
        Property '"has_relatives"' is incompatible with index signature.
          Type '{ records: ({ kids: { has_phone?: undefined; }; } | { kids: { has_phone: { records: never[]; }; }; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'RecordedNode'.
            Types of property 'records' are incompatible.
              Type '({ kids: { has_phone?: undefined; }; } | { kids: { has_phone: { records: never[]; }; }; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Node[]'.
                Type '{ kids: { has_phone?: undefined; }; } | { kids: { has_phone: { records: never[]; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
                  Type '{ kids: { has_phone?: undefined; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Node'.
                    Types of property 'kids' are incompatible.
                      Type '{ has_phone?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'NodeKids'.
                        Property '"has_phone"' is incompatible with index signature.
                          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RecordedNode'.ts(2322)
'dataTyped' is assigned a value but never used.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

However, the fun part is that if I inline it, ie

```
let xxxx: Node[] = <COPY THE CONTENTS OF JSON>
```

The error disappears.

Answer (score -1):

I checked it on the playground (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and it, well, doesn't show the error.

The typescript version is 3.9.2 (could be a bug on your TS version?). The only other difference is that here we don't import the json but parse it from the string.

```
const json = `
[
   {
      "kids":{
         "has_relatives":{
            "records":[
               {
                  "kids":{

                  }
               },
               {
                  "kids":{
                     "has_phone":{
                        "records":[

                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
 ]
`
const data =JSON.parse(json);
console.log(data);

interface Node {
  kids: NodeKids
}

interface NodeAttributes {
  [key: string]: string;
}

interface NodeKids {
  [key: string]: RecordedNode;
}

interface RecordedNode {
  records: Node[]
}

let dataTyped: Node[] = data
```

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I wrote at the bottom of my question;) after changinng the version it started working

Comment: Ah, so it was (probably) a bug in typescript.

Comment: JSON.parse returns `any`, so of course there's not going to be an error!

Comment: Correct, that test is pretty useless because typescript does not parse at compile time and con't detect any error here. Which, on the other hand, tells me, that typescript parses imported json at compile time. That's interesting.